# Text Overlapping CSS Styling

Tags: html, css

I have a line like this:

```
<li>Some text here<span style="float:right;">Hello</span></li>
```

The idea is that the word 'Hello' is aligned to the right of the main text on the same line.

The problem is that when the screen size shrinks, the two pieces of text overlap each other making a mess.

I want the 'Some text here' part to wrap onto another line and not overlap the 'Hello' part.

Comment: Using a media screen query to adjust the position won't help because the 'Some text here' part can be of any length because it's in a list, so the point at which the media part is activated is not constant.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a CSS Media Query to the "Hello" part so than when the screen is smaller the Hello text gets moved to a new line.

HTML

```
<li>Some text here<span class="move-text">Hello</span></li>
```

CSS

```
.move-text{
    float: right;

@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  .move-text {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can just remove the float on the "Hello" text, either way will work.

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  .move-text {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Hope this was helpful! Comment if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the easiest way to fix it is to do away with list items and instead use a table with invisible borders where each item of text is in a separate cell, and additionally, each cell is text top aligned so the result is even better than first expected.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

You can use media query for this. For example screen 600 px wide or less;

```
  <style>
 @media screen and (max-width:600px){
 span{
      float:none;
      width:100%;
       }
     }
  </style>
```